# Going back in time to see if a value exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a need to create a query in SQL that will take a record set (the select statement) and return the last value for price change that happened. so something like this scenario.

```
--Create a TableVariable(only in memory)
Declare @CarPrices Table (testid int, car nvarchar(50),price 
nvarchar(50),PricingDate date)
--Insert Data
insert into @CarPrices (testid, car, price, PricingDate) values (1, 'Ford', 
'1.00043', '05/15/2018')
insert into @CarPrices (testid, car, price, PricingDate) values (2, 
'Chevy','1.00043', '05/15/2018')
insert into @CarPrices (testid, car, price, PricingDate) values (3, 'Chevy', 
NULL, '05/16/2018')
insert into @CarPrices (testid, car, price, PricingDate) values (4, 'Ford', 
NULL, '05/16/2018')
insert into @CarPrices (testid, car, price, PricingDate) values (5, 'Ford', 
'1.0053', '05/17/2018')
insert into @CarPrices (testid, car, price, PricingDate) values (6, 'Chevy', 
NULL, '05/17/2018')
insert into @CarPrices (testid, car, price, PricingDate) values (7, 'Chevy', 
NULL, '05/18/2018')
insert into @CarPrices (testid, car, price, PricingDate) values (8, 'Ford', 
NULL, '05/18/2018')
insert into @CarPrices (testid, car, price, PricingDate) values (9, 'Audi', 
'10.0003', '05/18/2018')
```

Objective: Look through the data set and get the most current car date and price

Any thoughts or anything to try. I don't have a data set to work with that is small enough so I'm using cars and pricing and dates which in essence is what I will be doing on a larger scale. Any thoughts? Maybe a complex case statement of an IIF statement? I really don't know where to start on this one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This forum is mainly for specific programming/technical questions, so if you are just looking for comments/suggestions, then this isn't the best place for that.  If you can add some data/SQL to your question, we would be happy to help you.

Comment: I'll update with some code tomorrow, I don't have the sample code i'm working with.  Thanks Tim

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: So the NULLs are irrelevant, you just want the most recent valid price? The old style way is to write a query that finds the most recent valid date then uses that to look back in. The new style is to use windowing functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a `MAX()` on a filtered `NOT NULL` price should do the trick.

```
;WITH MostRecentCarPriceDay AS
(
    SELECT
        C.Car,
        MaxDay = MAX(C.Day)
    FROM
        CarPrices AS C
    WHERE
        C.day >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 6) AND
        C.Price IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        C.Car
)
SELECT
    C.Car,
    C.Day,
    C.Price
FROM
    CarPrices AS C
    INNER JOIN MostRecentCarPriceDay AS M ON
        C.Car = M.Car AND
        C.Day = M.MaxDay
```

Comment: Thank you EzLo,  that will be a good solution for them.  I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Using an outer apply to the previous non-null prices of the same car could do the trick

```
declare @T table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, Car varchar(30), [day] date, price money);

insert into @T (Car, [day], price) values
('ford', '2018-05-13',5003.00),
('Chevy','2018-05-13',8003.00),
('ford', '2018-05-14',5004.00),
('Chevy','2018-05-14',null),
('ford', '2018-05-15',null),
('Chevy','2018-05-15',8005.00);

select Car, [day], price, coalesce(price, prevPrice) as CorrectedPrice
from @T t1
outer apply 
(
  select top 1 price as prevPrice 
  from @T t2 
  where t2.Car = t1.Car
  and t2.[day] < t1.[day]
  and datediff(day,t2.[day],t1.[day]) <= 5 -- only the previous 5 days
  and t1.price is null 
  and t2.price is not null 
  order by t2.[day] desc
) q1
order by t1.Car, t1.[day];
```

Result:

```
Car    day         price    CorrectedPrice
-----  ----------  -------  --------------
Chevy  2018-05-13  8003,00  8003,00
Chevy  2018-05-14  NULL     8003,00
Chevy  2018-05-15  8005,00  8005,00
ford   2018-05-13  5003,00  5003,00
ford   2018-05-14  5004,00  5004,00
ford   2018-05-15  NULL     5004,00
```